# Can Azure Data Factory invoke an Azure Virtual Machine?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have an Azure Data Factory pipeline. I want the pipeline to run a command on an existing Azure Virtual Machine, perhaps with ssh. I cannot find any mention of this in the ADF documentation. The closest thing is to use Azure Batch to access some (new) VMs that hold the software I want. But I would like to do this without Batch, just have ADF control an existing Azure VM.

Sounds simple and obvious. Does anyone know how to do this, or knows that it is not possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can run an Azure Funcion activity from an Azure Data Factory:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-azure-function-activity

Azure functions call be written in Powershell:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-powershell

You can then use the az vm run command to execute a script on a virtual machine

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm/run-command?view=azure-cli-latest#az-vm-run-command-invoke

Comment: Thank you. Any tips for making this secure, so only my instance of Data Factory could invoke a shell script on the VM?

Answer (score 0):

All of the supported Activities (as both *source* and *sink*) are fully documented. There is no specific way of talking directly to a VM; you'd need to set up your own listener on your VM (since generic HTTP & REST are supported *sinks*). There is no `ssh` *sink*.

More details on Activities: [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipelines-activities#data-movement-activities).

Comment: Thank you for the sink listener idea.